# Unable To RDP To VM Host On External Network

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rdp, essentials-2012-r2

Weird problem here that occurs on all servers i roll out for clients.

I am unable to RDP to the VM host using Windows RDP, teamviewer, tight VNC, etc. Just hangs on "initiating remote connection" then says "remote desktop cant connect to the remote computer..."

I am able to from an external network access the VM, any other PC and am also able to RDP out of every PC on that network too including the VM.

I am also able to RDP 'OUT' of the host just not to the host externally although i 'AM' able to RDP to the host if i RDP to a local PC then relay to the host. The issue is that if there is an issue with DNS/DHCP on the VM (manages these features) then i would be unable to access the host so would like to be able to directly.

We are running Windows 2012 R2 Essentials on the host using the single CAL on the VM.

Also note that i have set up the port forwarding rules for both Tight VNC and RDP. Tried disabling firewall. Remote access is allowed in system settings. Able to ping and RDP locally just not externally.

yep, just can not get to the server directly. Server and VM share the same NIC, both can be pinged from any PC on the network and any PC on the network can be pinged by them. break it down a bit for you:

Internet>Firewall>VM/OtherPConNetwork = Success.

VM/otherPConNetwork>ServerHost = Success.

ServerHost>VM/OtherPConNetwork = Success.

Internet>Firewall>ServerHost = Fail.

Comment: So, to clarify: _Remote => internet => NAT/firewall => server_ fails but _Remote => internet => NAT/firewall => other PC => Server_ succeeds?

Comment: And are all the affected servers either behind the same hardware NAT/firewall, or same brand of firewall?

Comment: yep, just can not get to the server directly. Server and VM share the same NIC, both can be pinged from any PC on the network and any PC on the network can be pinged by them. break it down a bit for you: Internet>Firewall>VM/otherPConNetwork = Success.  
      VM/otherPConNetwork>ServerHost = Success.  
      ServerHost>VM/OtherPConNetwork = Success.  
      PConDifferentNetwork>VM/OtherPConNetwork = Success.  
      PConDifferentNetwork>ServerHost = Fail.